# Using Shape Drawable or Custom View?

Tags: android, view, shapedrawable

We can draw approximately all things in canvas in `onDraw` method of a customview.Also Docs say:

> When you want to dynamically draw some two-dimensional graphics, a
>   ShapeDrawable object will probably suit your needs.

My question is simple,when we have to use custom view and when ShapeDrawable?Or it is best we combine them?if it is true,**What is the strengths and weaknesses of these options?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think `ShapeDrawable` is easier to use, cause you can use it in `Selector`, for example, and create button with custom background and click animation without writing any code at all (just using XML). On the other hand, this drawables are pretty limited, and if you need  your own control with non-standart tuch interception you defenatelly must create your own custom `View`.

So i think it's better to combine them, because somtimes you need something simple and `ShapeDrawables` is real fast and good solution for it, but if you want something real speccial OR something that you can archive using shapes, here you must write your own `View`.